# Controlling Navigation Using PageTransitions in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a main window and two pages.

What I want in my program is that when the main window is loaded it loads the 1st page (within the main window) with fade transition. When I click a button in the 1st page it should remove the first page and the 2nd page appears in the main window.

I'm using the Fyslexic Duck Page Transition to animate the appearance of the page.

My problem is when the 1st page is loaded in the main window and then I click on the button of the 1st page I have no Idea how to unload the 1st page and make the 2nd page appear with transition in the main window.

Here is my Code:

**MAIN WINDOW.XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="LoyaltyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:pageTransitions="clr-namespace:WpfPageTransitions;assembly=WpfPageTransitions"
        Title="Loyalty Application" Height="694.5" Width="1305.5"
        ResizeMode="NoResize" Name="mainWindow" Loaded="mainWindow_Loaded">
    <!--<Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/home.png"/>
    </Window.Background>-->

    <Grid>

        <pageTransitions:PageTransition Name="pageTransitionControl" TransitionType="SlideAndFade">
        </pageTransitions:PageTransition>
  </Grid>

</Window>
```

**MAIN WINDOW.CS**

```
 private void mainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Home newPage = new Home();
            pageTransitionControl.TransitionType = PageTransitionType.Fade;
            pageTransitionControl.ShowPage(newPage);

        }
```

---

**HOME.XAML** (Page1)

```
<UserControl x:Class="LoyaltyApp.Home"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="694.5" d:DesignWidth="1305.5">
    <UserControl.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/home.png"/>
    </UserControl.Background>
    <Grid>

<Button Content="Button" Width="203" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**HOME.CS** (Page1)

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Transitions to Next Page or Page 2
        }
```

---

**PAGE2.CS**

```
 private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                // Transitions back to Home (Page1)
            }
 private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                {
                    // Transitions to Next Page or Page 3
                }
```

Thank you. Hope to get feedback from you guys.

Transition Reference link:
http://www.fyslexicduck.com/2011/05/page-transition-control-for-wpf.html

Answer (score 0):

In `MainWindow.cs`, expose a public method called `ShowPage`, which takes the new page as parameter.

```
public void ShowPage(UserControl newPage)
{
    if (newPage != null)  
        pageTransitionControl.ShowPage(newPage);
}
```

Then in every page you can access this method like this

```
((MainWindow)App.Current.MainWindow).ShowPage(newPage);
```

For example, from Home page to PAGE2

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((MainWindow)App.Current.MainWindow).ShowPage(new PAGE2());
}
```

from PAGE2 to PAGE3

```
((MainWindow)App.Current.MainWindow).ShowPage(new PAGE3());
```

Navigating from Page2 *back* to Home is something different, from the link, the pages are pushed into a Stack, so the transition control may provide a `Goback()` method, instead of requiring you to navigate to a *new* Home page like this

```
((MainWindow)App.Current.MainWindow).ShowPage(new Home());
```

But I am not sure if it has a `Goback()` method.